# QR Code - is uniqueness guaranteed for unique inputs

Tags: qr-code, barcode, barcode-scanner

I want to generate QR codes to pass a unique alpha-numeric code to a site. The QR will be generated from  a string like:

```
https://example.com/ABCD1234
```

The ABCD1234 is the unique code and there will be ~100 million of them. Can I be sure no two QR codes will be the same, and be read to 100% accuracy?

Anything to watch out for standards wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100% is too pure of a number to get specific advice.  This reply is general, and not meant for any super mission critial needs.

The clarity of barcodes in general depends on the quality of the printed image, as well as the reader's ability to decode (optics and decoder).  QR codes have some error correction attributes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code).  Commercial decoders, even for webcams, are used widely for consumer and retail applications.

Keep in mind, barcodes were designed for reading labels quickly, and often while moving.  They are not well suited for things like security codes, where deep levels of checks are needed. It is possible for things to go wrong.

Given that, it really depends on what you mean by 100%. The barcode symbology cannot make many guarantees, but the content might begin to.   If your line-of-business app is mildly mission critical, and your app can control what's printed on labels, and the http address is to 'your' line-of-business web site, you could append a check value within the content, in the QR code printed.  For example, ~https://example.com/ABC1234?check=5551212, has a check value which the web site can optionally verify.  However, the more content you have, the more dense the printed pattern will get (and possibly more difficult to read).

Comment: Sorry for my late reply and thanks for answer. To expand my question, currently the ABCD1234 code is printed in plain text and manually entered into a site. Checks are done there. I'm suggesting to put the number in  QR as part of a URL. Checks at the website end will still be done (does it match against database etc). So the security is not in the QR itself, the QR is simply a means to pass the code onto the web site, With that in mind, is QR suitable for so many unique codes (or URLs really)?

Comment: Good idea to add in extra checking like you describe, will do that. And also do extensive testing on various error checking levels vs ease of scanning in various devices.

Comment: Yes, QR is suitable for URLs.  
Depending on the version of QR, you can encode roughly up to 3 KB of bytes or less. For some background, check out the specs from DENSO at https://www.qrcode.com/en/faq.html